# How to select the first number of elements with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, dom

For example, let's say I have 25 **images** in a webpage

My question is: how do I select the first 6 **images** so that I can change the `setAttribute` to something else.

But I don't want to do this

```
document.queryselectorAll('img')[0]
document.queryselectorAll('img')[1]
document.queryselectorAll('img')[2]
document.queryselectorAll('img')[3]
document.queryselectorAll('img')[4]
document.queryselectorAll('img')[5]
```

I need a much easier way to write all that
**Help**

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? `.querySelectorAll()` uses CSS selectors. That would be one possible way...

Comment: Use quantity selectors: https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css/#section8

Comment: What about `for (let i=0; i < 6; i++) { ...... }` ?

Answer (score 2):

**Why not do a loop?**

### Logic

First we use `querySelectorAll()` to query the DOM and store the NodeList in a variable `images`. Then we loop to change the elements attributes.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('doIt'),
      images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

function addImages(){
  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
     images[i].setAttribute('src', `https://picsum.photos/id/${i}/100/100`);
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', addImages);
```

```html
<img src=""></img>
<img src=""></img>
<img src=""></img>
<img src=""></img>
<img src=""></img>
<img src=""></img>
<img src=""></img>
<p>
<input type="button" id="doIt" value="add images"/>
```

Comment: Why query the DOM for all images over and over again?

Comment: @AbrahamEbijuni You should really not do it like that. Use a CSS selector, or query the DOM once and store the result in a variable and use that variable. Querying the DOM `n` times just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Andreas could you expand on that? Maybe it would be a good idea if you answered this question as well..

Comment: The relevant information is mentioned in the comments on OPs question.

Comment: But why "Querying the DOM n times just doesn't make sense." ?

Comment: Because one `.querySelectorAll()` call is enough. There won't be any changes in the DOM between each round of your loop.

Comment: You are completely right. Thanks.